# How can you use the python module MC Status To Check if a server is online or not?

Tags: python

I have tried to figure out how I could devise a way of checking if my Minecraft server is online with mcstatus, a python module, by checking the latency but I don't really know how I could wait for a certain amount of time after attempting to check its latency, so does anyone have anything that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

i use like in pip webpage show to use

```
from mcstatus import MinecraftServer

# If you know the host and port, you may skip this and use MinecraftServer("example.org", 1234)
server = MinecraftServer.lookup("example.org:1234")

# 'status' is supported by all Minecraft servers that are version 1.7 or higher.
status = server.status()
print("The server has {0} players and replied in {1} ms".format(status.players.online, status.latency))

# 'ping' is supported by all Minecraft servers that are version 1.7 or higher.
# It is included in a 'status' call, but is exposed separate if you do not require the additional info.
latency = server.ping()
print("The server replied in {0} ms".format(latency))

# 'query' has to be enabled in a servers' server.properties file.
# It may give more information than a ping, such as a full player list or mod information.
query = server.query()
print("The server has the following players online: {0}".format(", ".join(query.players.names)))
```

you need to enable `query` in your minecraft server and `ping`

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know you had to enable it in the server.properties file, again thanks! Though do you know how you would check if the server is online, or does it say if it is if the server doesn't respond for long enough.

Comment: oh yeah i tried to ping the server, but i keep getting this error <bound method MinecraftServer.ping of <mcstatus.server.MinecraftServer object at 0x0000024A0D56A550>>

Comment: oh nvm i fixed it, no i can devise a way of checking if the server is online or not, thanks again!